# C# Get data between date and hour from MySQL table

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime-format, time-format

I'm trying to print a table from my database but I want to filter it using this block code, what I want to do is print the data between two hours but I don't know is the input format of the hour is correct, so here's the code:

```
    string horaI=null;
    string horaF=null;
    string[] hr1 = null;
    string[] hr2 = null;

    on load....
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt"; // Only use hours and minutes
    horaI = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("HH:mm tt");
    hr1 = horaI.Split();

    string connectionstring = null;
    string sql = null;
    string data = null;

    connectionstring = "server=127.0.0.1; database=gimnasio5; uid=root; pwd=0000000000;";

        sql = "SELECT IdMembresia, Nombre, Apellido, Tipo, Fecha_Inicio,
   Fecha_Vencimiento, Inscripcion, Total,Impreso_Corte FROM membresia where
   Impreso_Corte='No impreso' or (Fecha_Membresia between @d1 and @d2 and
   Hora_Membresia between @d3 and @d4) order by gimnasio5.membresia.IdMembresia;";

        var dtable = new DataTable("membresia");
        var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
        var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        var dscmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        using (conn)
        {

            var param = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@d1", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Date);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.Value = DateTime.Today;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@d2", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Date);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.Value = DateTime.Today;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

 //The error can be here because when I use it with dates only it works fine
 //but when I add this part of code, fails. 

            param = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@d3", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Time);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.Value = hr1[0];  //Convert.ToDateTime(hr1[0]).ToString("HH:mm");
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@d4", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Time);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.Value = hr2[0];  //Convert.ToDateTime(hr2[0]).ToString("HH:mm");
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            conn.Open();
            dscmd.Fill(dtable);
        }
```

> But Im geting and error: An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

I get the error when I try to fill the MySqlAdapter Object:

> dscmd.Fill(dtable);

I thought it was the format I input the time, but as you can see in the code I use to forms for it, but neither of both works, and returns the same error code.
My column in the MySQL database is set to save time type, so the problem isn't in the table.

The hour in the database is saved like this, the column is time type:

> 12:03:00
>
> 21:34:00

Thanks in advanced.

Table structure

```
   CREATE TABLE `membresia` (
   `IdMembresia` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `Apellido` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `Tipo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `Fecha_Inicio` date NOT NULL,
   `Fecha_Vencimiento` date NOT NULL,
   `Inscripcion` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Estado_membresia` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `Fecha_modificacion` date NOT NULL,
   `Total` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
   `Nota` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Fecha_Membresia` date NOT NULL,
   `Impreso_Corte` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `IdSocio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Hora_Membresia` time NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`IdMembresia`),
   KEY `L_Id2` (`IdSocio`),
   KEY `F_Nombre` (`Nombre`),
   KEY `F_Apelli` (`Apellido`),
   CONSTRAINT `F_Apelli` FOREIGN KEY (`Apellido`) REFERENCES `socios` (`Apellido`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `F_Nombre` FOREIGN KEY (`Nombre`) REFERENCES `socios` (`Nombre`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `L_Id2` FOREIGN KEY (`IdSocio`) REFERENCES `socios` (`IdSocio`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you please share your table structure with us?

Comment: yeah I write the structure now you can see it

Comment: You don't need Using(conn) this method...just edit this query according to your application. You need to pass time from datetimepicker....tell me if you have probs.

Comment: yeah, I'm erasing the code

Comment: You need 4 datetime picker because you want to check 1st on date range and second time range

Comment: Look **Fecha_Membresia` date NOT NULL,** --> Date Formate so you need to pass date Range I mean fromDate and toDate and for **Hora_Membresia` time NOT NULL,** you need to pass fromTime to toTime. Ok FYI you can get date and time both from dateTimePicker. See my query parameter there I fetched time and date individually from datetime picker.

Comment: is correct but still fetching individually I can't get data the error dissapear

Comment: Set a debug point to **SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);** this line and the move your courser to query variable and the copy the query.....and paste or you can paste it on your sql server to run and test. I hope you can figure out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107895/discussion-between-bluetoothfx-and-user2461687).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code like this way:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1; database=gimnasio5; uid=root; pwd=0000000000;");

        conn.Open();

        string query = string.Format(@"SELECT IdMembresia, Nombre, Apellido, Tipo, Fecha_Inicio,
                       Fecha_Vencimiento, Inscripcion, Total, Impreso_Corte FROM membresia where
                       Impreso_Corte = 'No impreso' or(Fecha_Membresia between '{0}' and '{1}' and
                       Hora_Membresia between '{2}' and '{3}') order by gimnasio5.membresia.IdMembresia", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString(), dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString(), dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), dateTimePicker4.Value.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        conn.Close();
        return dt;
```

Comment: it doesn't give me the error now but I'm not getting data

Comment: I think the input param value and db value not matching. So check input param and db value...

Comment: well I'll check it

Comment: I found the error is the string date format (hh:mm:ss) and I need in 24 hours format (HH:mm:ss)

Comment: Set you datetimepicker as like image (click on link). and to get time write like=>>      **string time = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss");**           [Click here to see DateTimePicker as TimePicker](http://i.imgur.com/Vxxuh1t.png)